# How can we find out if a package is available for .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-framework-version

Basically I write a code in 4.6 .NET Framework. Now I want it to convert it to .NET Core so I am checking in cs.proj file that which package is available for .NET Core. Then I try to search on Google; I found that package but it does not include any information related to .NET Framework or .NET Core and for which version it is applicable?

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.1.1.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This is one of those packages. Now how should I check if this one is available for .NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

Go into dependencies section of nuget you will find this package is availabel for which framework or core [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces)

Answer (score -2):

> Now how should i check this one is availabel for .net core 3.1

As per [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces):

> This package is not required starting with .NET Standard 2.1 and .NET
>   Core 3.0.

So you don't need the package if you are working in .NET Core 3.x (since it is already in `System.Runtime`).

Comment: thanks for comment .But i am taking in general way .let we take this package Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.dll this package not containe any information on google https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager/ . my question is just is their any general way to detect for each package